# python pass multiple parameters to function that expects function

Tags: python-3.x, function

I am stuck on a problem and I would be grateful for help.
Consider the following example.

```
# can be changed
def inner(x):
    x = 4
    return x

# can not be changed
def outer(a, b):
    b = b(b)
    return a + b

# can be changed - I want to pass two parameters to inner
res = outer(
    a = 3,
    b = inner
)

print(res)
```

Now important to note is that **I can not change the function outer()**, because it comes from a common code base / package.

How can I pass multiple parameters to inner()? inner() can be changed as needed, but it needs to return the function, not the int since outer() expects a function.

Thank you in advance!

I tried passing multiple parameters, but outer() expects a function. This example illustrates the function ExternalTaskSensor of the python package airflow. The parameter

```
execution_date_fn
```

expects a function to be returned.

Comment: So you want to pass to the `inner` function  `n` numbers of functions and then what?

Comment: And how do you expect to sum a & b if a is an `int` and b is a `func`?